# Combining errors in a histogram (binned data)

Tags: python, histogram, binning

I'm processing some data that requires binning before it goes through a regression algorithm.  The script is in Python and uses the Numpy `histogram` function, but the code should be self explanatory.  For reference, `histogram` outputs either an array containing the integer number of points in each bin, or you can weight by the value of the points in the bin (e.g. a sum).  The y errors are standard devs.

So the data is binned like:

```
#Number of items in each bin
(binned, dump) = np.histogram(x,bins)
#Binned data, weighted by value of each point
(xbinned, dump) = np.histogram(x,bins, weight=x)
#etc for y and y error ...
```

The errors on the y values (this assumes no x errors) are weighted by the variance so the errors are added in quadrature:

```
(varbinned, dump) = np.histogram(x,bins,weight=error**2)
```

To finish off the function returns an averaged array of points, e.g.

```
xbinned = xbinned/binned
```

What I'm not sure about is how to handle the errors.  The result should be square rooted (to convert back from the summed variances), but how is the number of bins factored into the answer?  Is it as straightforward as doing:

```
errorbinned = np.sqrt(varbinned/binned)
```

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Out of curiosity, what regression algorithm requires binning?  (2) Is the binned variable an independent variable in the regression or a dependent variable?

Comment: 1) The data is pretty noisy (and around 2000 points), so binning should help cut down the error bars a bit.  The actual regression function is a reasonably simple Normal Equations job fitting a straight line.

2) Both x, y and y errors are binned.  It's x = time, y = counts, yerror = count error.  The number of bins is based on the time range, so somewhere in the code there is a statement that divides up x into however many slices and the y/yerror data is binned up as appropriate.

Comment: I am browsing some unanswered questions.  Your response for 1) is not correct. Binning does not reduce noise. It just shoves it under the carpet after magnifying it.

Comment: Given that this is a 12 year old question... 

My guess is that this was from a photometry application (astronomy) where binning is routinely used to improve SNR i.e. binned signal is sum(counts) for N pixels, but SNR improves as sqrt(N).